# Glassfish, cannot find folder portlet-container in glassfish/domain/domain1

Tags: java, installation, glassfish, portlet

Hello I need to run portlets on glassfish and use netbeans for development, downloaded netbeans 7.0 with bundle glassfish, installed. Then went to http://portlet-container.java.net/public/Download.html page, downloaded jar, then tried to install, here have problem it cannot find portlet-container in folder glassfish/domain/domain1. I opened directory /usr/local/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1, but there us no any portlet-container folder!
 
What I must do to install portlet container to glassfish?
Here the actual Error:

SEVERE: Portlet Container configuration Failed. /usr/local/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/portlet-container/portlet-container.zip (No such file or directory)

Comment: problem solved, just sudo java -jar, solves that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the portlet container installer assumes that you have write permission in the domain1 directory.  If you have installed GlassFish into /usr/local, you may not have write permission... which is what you discovered.

You can run the portlet container installer as root or you can do the following (which doesn't require rootiness):

```
asadmin create-domain --domaindir ~/myDomains --adminport 4848 domain1
```

Then run the installer and specifiy ~/myDomains/domain1 for the domain dir.